# Dart fromJson cannot parse double values

Tags: dart, fromjson

I'm having problem using fromJson in flutter. I'm receiving my data like this

`{id: d7ba912e-69fd-11ea-9ab0-6597c4120b03, receipt_date: 2020-03-18T17:30:00.000Z, customer_id: e3fedf5e, amount: 2500, remark: Amount 2500, created_on: 2020-03-19T16:22:35.000Z, collectionSize: 3, name: Customer 1}`

And I'm using this fromJson to parse:

`factory CashReceipt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CashReceipt(
        id: json['id'],
        customerId: json['customer_id'],
        date: json['date'] as DateTime,
        amount: json['amount'] as double,
        remark: json['remark']);
  }`

The "amount" property is double in my model. It is causing following error. The data coming from API is "amount:2500". It goes away if I change the "amount" to "int". But it is not right. Your help is much appreciated.

```
_CastError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
num amount
```

instead of

```
double amount
```

and you will not get this error. see this [doc](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/num-class.html)